# How to databind for Eval function in codebehind in asp.net gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am working on a parent/child gridview in asp.net C#. My data is in the form getter/setter unlike typical custom collection. Because of this I have to databind in codebehind and unable to use Eval() function. I do data binding as shown below under CodeBehind. I don't know how can I data bing for ',    'one');"> as shown under aspx code. In order to populate Customer ID, I only have a method called GetCustomerID() which I can use in the code behind, and I don't have a property named CustoemrID

CodeBehind:

```
protected void grdMain_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var customers = new Customers();

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        customers = (Customers)e.Row.DataItem;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = customers.GetDate();
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = customers.GetName();
    }
}
```

aspx code:

```
<Columns>             
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('div<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>', 'one');">
                <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>" src="images/plus.bmp"/>
            </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have used in our project. Please try it may work for you.

> <img id='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' src="images/plus.bmp" >

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

ASPX code:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('<%# "div" + Convert.ToString(Eval("CustomerID")) %>','one');">
                <img id='<%# "imgdiv" + Convert.ToString(Eval("CustomerID")) %>' src="images/plus.bmp" />
                 </a>
           </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: As I have mentioned I don't have a property called CustomerID, I only have a method named GetCustomerID() which I can use in the code behind.